# After initial setup cannot sign in to Foreman web console with admin account

Tags: puppet, puppetmaster, rubygems, foreman, puppet-foreman

Edited post to show how I installed foreman

I'm new to ruby and I am trying to install Foreman on CentOS 7.

I followed the [install guide](http://theforeman.org/manuals/1.9/quickstart_guide.html) for my distro to do this:

1. sudo yum -y install epel-release
2. sudo rpm -ivh
   http://yum.puppetlabs.com/puppetlabs-release-el-7.noarch.rpm
3. sudo yum -y install
   http://yum.theforeman.org/releases/1.9/el7/x86_64/foreman-release.rpm
4. sudo yum install foreman-installer
5. sudo foreman-installer
6. puppet agent --test

Here are the foreman packages it installed:

```
sudo rpm -qa foreman*
foreman-release-1.9.3-1.el7.noarch
foreman-postgresql-1.9.3-1.el7.noarch
foreman-1.9.3-1.el7.noarch
foreman-installer-1.9.3-1.el7.noarch
foreman-debug-1.9.3-1.el7.noarch
foreman-selinux-1.9.3-1.el7.noarch
foreman-release-scl-1-1.el7.x86_64
foreman-proxy-1.9.3-1.el7.noarch
foreman-cli-1.9.3-1.el7.noarch
```

I set it up but cannot login with the default admin and password "changeme".

I attempted to reset the password, but got this error:

```
sudo foreman-rake password=123456
rake aborted!
Please install the sqlite3 adapter: `gem install activerecord-sqlite3-adapter` (Could not find sq...
```

Running `gem install activerecord-sqlite3-adapter` gives me another error:

```
gem install activerecord-sqlite3-adapter
ERROR:  Could not find a valid gem 'activerecord-sqlite3-adapter' (>= 0) in any repository
```

Google told me this seems to be a version mismatch and a possible solution is to put this in my Gemfile:

```
gem 'sqlite3'
```

and run

```
bundle install
```

Where is the foreman gem file located?

I got some stuff under a folder named "rh" in opt:

```
sudo find -name Gemfile
./rh/ruby193/root/usr/share/gems/gems/deep_cloneable-2.0.2/Gemfile
./rh/ruby193/root/usr/share/gems/gems/oauth-0.4.7/Gemfile
./rh/ruby193/root/usr/share/gems/gems/mail-2.4.4/Gemfile
./rh/ruby193/root/usr/share/gems/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/templates/Gemfile
./rh/ruby193/root/usr/share/gems/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/generators/rails/app/templates/Gemfile
./rh/ruby193/root/usr/share/gems/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/generators/rails/plugin_new/templates/Gemfile
```

Edit:

I installed foreman-sqlite and was able to run foreman-rake

```
sudo foreman-rake password=123456

/opt/rh/ruby193/root/usr/bin/ruby -I"lib:test" -I"/opt/rh/ruby193/root/usr/share/gems/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib" "/opt/rh/ruby193/root/usr/share/gems/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/rake_test_loader.rb" "test/lib/**/*_test.rb"
```

But when I try to sign on as admin with password 123456 it still says "Incorrect username or password".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would be useful to know how you installed Foreman, but I'm going to guess that you've done a `yum install foreman` and haven't [used the installer](http://theforeman.org/manuals/latest/quickstart_guide.html).  I'll just note that the installer is recommended as it will set up PostgreSQL, Passenger, a Puppet master, smart proxy etc. automatically.

You will need to choose and set up a database first - PostgreSQL, MySQL or SQLite, then configure `/etc/foreman/database.yml` to point to it.  SQLite doesn't need any extra configuration, that's the default you're seeing.

Next, `yum install` either `foreman-sqlite`, `foreman-postgresql` or `foreman-mysql2` as appropriate.  This will fix the adapter error.  I strongly recommend against running gem or bundle commands on a package installation as you'll create a mix of unpackaged and packaged dependencies.

Once the DB's configured and the adapter installed, run `foreman-rake db:migrate` and `foreman-rake db:seed` to set up the contents.  The db:seed command will print a random password (default is not changeme any more).

If you don't get or lose the password from db:seed, run `foreman-rake permissions:reset` to regenerate one.

Comment: Edited post to show how I installed foreman

Comment: Installing foreman-sqlite seemed to solve the initial problem, but after resetting the password I still can't login with the admin account.

Comment: sudo foreman-rake permissions:reset was all I needed to do. It reset the password and I could login.

Comment: Good to hear.  Using the installer should have set it up with PostgreSQL, so I'd consider re-running it to see if there were any errors.  SQLite will work to begin with, but it only works for a few hosts before you'll get locking errors.